# como quitar el carácter "," antes del salto de linea en archivo csv

Tags: mysql, csv

tengo un csv y necesito cargarlo a mysql el archivo es algo asi

```
n1,n2,n3,n4
n1,n2,n3,n4
n1,n2,n3,n4,
n1,n2,n3,n4,
n1,n2,n3,n4,
n1,n2,n3,n4,
```

lo que necesito es que si antes del salto de linea existe una "," esta sea eliminada para que el resutado sea el siguiente

```
 n1,n2,n3,n4
 n1,n2,n3,n4
 n1,n2,n3,n4
 n1,n2,n3,n4
 n1,n2,n3,n4
 n1,n2,n3,n4
```

la DB la cargo asi

```
ALTER TABLE `e_2018s` ;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/lampp/htdocs/db/2018/blok/res.csv'
INTO TABLE `e_2018s`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ALTER TABLE `e_2018s` ENABLE KEYS;
```

use
`sed 's/,$//' test.csv > res.csv1`
con menos archivos  y funciono correctamente parece que el problema es cuando  lo hago sobre el csv de >10gb

estoy usando debian 10 booster

Comment: No debería haber problema, bastaría con ignorar ese último elemento vacío. ¿Cómo haces la carga?

Comment: Estas trabajando en algun lenguaje de programación?? O se lo estas tirando directamente a la BD??

Comment: Indica el código o procedimiento que estás intentando para hacer esto. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: las lineas de un csv deben terminar en \r\n (CRLF)

Comment: @Japv Sólo se estila CRLF en Windows. Los csv no sólo se usan en Windows.

Comment: Depués de cargar ¿Revisaste `show warnings;`?